# Correct API for accepting credit cards directly on my site using PayPal?

Tags: paypal, credit-card

We need to accept credit cards (from anywhere in the world) directly on our website. We'd like to use PayPal, but NOT require a PayPal account. The user should be able to simply type in the credit card, date and cvv directly on our site and go. I'm having a hard time figuring out what PayPal API I need to use for this, to integrate with our Java-based server. Turns out PayPal has an overwhelming number of APIs and documentation.

It looks like [this link](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/direct-payment/ht_dp-singleAuthPayment-curl-etc/) is what I'm looking for... sort of. But can I post this directly from JavaScript? It includes account name and password, which would be in the clear for anyone to see, so I'm thinking this must be server-side code. So the idea is to use a [REST API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/) to do this? So the client must pass the credit card information to my server, which then calls PayPal's server?

I'm a little lost, when looking at all the APIs at the [Rest API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/) page. Which ones exactly do I need to use?

There is also [this link](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/accept-credit-cards/) but I'm not familiar with "curl" -- looking for Java. Maybe the distinction is minor and easy to convert from one to the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vern, if you look at the top of this page, you'll see Java (click Java) as one of the languages supported by the PayPal REST Payment API:
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/

You will see related sample requests that use the Java SDK:
https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-java

Comment: Thanks. Was just about to post a reply (to my own question) with basically the exact same response. I have found that the SDK contains not only complete examples for anything you might be interested in, but also complete documentation, helpful ReadMes, and more. In short, THIS is the place to start, NOT the documentation maze at the links in my original question.